# Outlook usertype not defined

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to make my Excel table to send me e-mail reminders to contact client when next deadline is met.

VBA gives me a

> VBA Compile error: User-defined type not defined

Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library is ticked.

```
Sub datesexcelvba()
    Dim myApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim mymail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim mydate1 As Date
    Dim mydate2 As Long
    Dim datetoday1 As Date
    Dim datetoday2 As Long

    Dim x As Long
    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastrow        
        mydate1 = Cells(x, 12).Value
        mydate2 = mydate1

        Cells(x, 15).Value = mydate2

        datetoday1 = Date
        datetoday2 = datetoday1

        Cells(x, 16).Value = datetoday

        If mydate2 - datetoday2 = 0 Then    
            Set myApp = New Outlook.Application
            Set mymail = myApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            mymail.To = Cells(x, 11).Value

            With mymail
                .Subject = "Reminder"
                .Body = Cells(x, 20).Text
                .Display
                '.send
            End With

            Cells(x, 13) = "Reminder sent"
            Cells(x, 13).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
            Cells(x, 13).Font.ColorIndex = 2
            Cells(x, 13).Font.Bold = True
            Cells(x, 14).Value = mydate2 - datetoday2  
        End If
    Next

    Set myApp = Nothing
    Set mymail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Expected result is that it sends me a reminder with body content from `(x, 20)` about those clients whose `mydate2 - datetoday = 0`.

Comment: Hallo, on what line you get the error?

Comment: Probably need to add a reference to the outlook library.

Comment: I got `LastRow` and `datetoday` undefined errors , but no ***User-defined type not defined*** error with your code

Comment: Same as @VincentG here. I copied your code and added MS Outlook 16 Object library and I'm not getting any compiler errors (though you would get them if you have `option explicit` in the module for *Variable Not Defined*

Comment: Note that you should specify a sheet for **every** `Cells` and `Range` like  `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells` otherwise Excel cannot know which sheet you mean and "guesses" (it might fail).

Answer (score 1):

Had to check the box for VBA->Tools->References->Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library

However, it is still not sending me reminders into my mailbox when deadlines are met automatically on scheduled time. Some other faulty code.